# How to dynamically adjust page height to its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm working on a website with an iFrame. The iFrame itself doesn't have scrollbars.

In that iFrame there are elements, that slide open when you click them. So the problem is that if you slide one open, which is bigger than the iFrame height, you are stuck there, as you can't scroll.

So I want that the height of the iFrame synchronises with the height of its content.

This is the jQuery code to slide one element open, which also then fits to its content:

```
$( "#effect1" ).animate({
    height: $( "#effect2" ).prop( "scrollHeight" )
}, 1000 );
$( "#effect2" ).animate({
    height: $( "#effect2" ).prop( "scrollHeight" ) - parseInt( $( "#effect2" ).css( "padding-top" ), 10 ) - parseInt( $( "#effect2" ).css( "padding-bottom" ), 10 )
}, 1000 );
```

So I guess it would be good to add the changing of the iFrame's height after that.

What I've tried so far:

I took some code from [this website](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/height/) dealing with the same problem.

```
function getDocHeight(doc) {
    doc = doc || document;
    // stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/
    var body = doc.body, html = doc.documentElement;
    var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
        html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
    return height;
}

function setIframeHeight(id) {
    var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);
    var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: 
        ifrm.contentWindow.document;
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    ifrm.style.height = "10px"; // reset to minimal height ...
    // IE opt. for bing/msn needs a bit added or scrollbar appears
    ifrm.style.height = getDocHeight( doc ) + 4 + "px";
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

So after the sliding of one iFrame's element I call `setIframeHeight("iframe");`. But there are two problems:

- it feels a bit ticky, as the height switches from one moment to another
- instead of increasing the iFrame's height, it increases the document's height

**So how can I dynamically adjust the iFrame's height?**

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many options. But no option is best.
You can try this way :

- In iframe, create an interval function (setInterval) run for each mili time to check document/element height changes. If it changed, call to parent window and pass with new height value and it will fit iframe window height.

Comment: Well but that's to hard-hitting on the CPU... I would rather find out why in my example it expands the HTML body of the parent frame and not the iFrame itself.